# How to configure a rcp product for win32 to correctly print German umlauts on the console?

Tags: java, windows, encoding, console, eclipse-rcp

I created a small Eclipse application that simply prints the string `äÄß` via `System.out`. When I run this application from within Eclipse the string is correctly printed out in the Eclipse console view. However if I build a product containing this application and start it on windows with `eclipsec.exe`, I see `a─▀` printed to the console.

The product definition is:

```xml
   <configIni use="default">
   </configIni>

   <launcherArgs>
      <programArgs>-consoleLog</programArgs>
      <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts</vmArgsMac>
   </launcherArgs>

   <windowImages/>

   <launcher>
      <solaris/>
      <win useIco="false">
         <bmp/>
      </win>
   </launcher>

   <vm>
   </vm>


   <plugins>
      <plugin id="console-encoding"/>
      <plugin id="javax.transaction" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.contenttype"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.jobs"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.app"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.preferences"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.registry"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi"/>
   </plugins>

   <configurations>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
   </configurations>
```

I tried to set the value of `osgi.console.encoding` to `Cp1252` and `console.encoding` also to `Cp1252`. I also tried changing the codepage of the command prompt where I start the eclipse application, but that didn't help either. When I'm typing German umlauts on the console they are displayed correctly.

What do I have to do to display the German umlauts on the console correctly?

**EDIT:**
I have modified the application to also read a line from `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))` and print that out too. When the codepage of the console is set to `Cp850` I can input `äÄß` and this is printed out. If I attach a debugger, I see that the input in eclipse looks like `„Žá`.

I also tried to explicitly specify the encoding via new `PrintStream(System.out, true, "Cp1252")`, but that didn't change anything.

I'm using Windows 7, just in case it matters.

Comment: Have you tried using PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "Cp1252"); out.println(); instead of System.out.println()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way of printing German umlauts to the console correctly is to use `System.console()` and the methods it provides.

Another way is to configure the encoding to be used externally, via a system property for example. Then the application has to use that encoding to create the necessary Writer, Readers and Streams. For Windows systems this encoding has to be `IBM850`.

The problem is that in Windows the default encoding `Cp1252` is used also for `System.out` and `System.in`. But the windows console uses `codepage 850` (a legacy from DOS times), which correspondents to the encoding `IBM850` in Java. Since `Cp1252`and `IBM850` are not compatible the characters get messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I assume you are using `org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsole`, which extends IOConsole. If you take a look at the IOConsole class, there is a `getEncodingMethod()`, which return default encoding, which is taken from `WorkbenchEncoding.getWorkbenchDefaultEncoding();`, which is `System.getProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");`. So, you could try to set property "`file.encoding`" to desired encoding. Hope this helps.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I already  tried changing the property value of `osgi.console.encoding`. If set this value overrides `file.encoding`. I'm not using `MessageConsole` explicitly. Just writing to `System.out`.